# Por que no debug do C++ palavras acentuadas e c cedilha aparecendo desconfiguradas?

Tags: c++

Ao debugar as palavras acentuadas desconfiguram. Como corrijo isso?
 Usando Visual Studio.

```
int main(){

int apples = 50;

cout << "Há"<< apples <<"maçãs."<< endl;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Pergunta relacionada no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1857668/520779). Não tenho experiência suficiente pra responder, mas me parece que o uso de caracteres acentuados num código-fonte C++ é "não-standard", por isso pode dar resultados diferentes de implementação pra implementação (inclusive diferença ao usar ou não o debugger). Seu problema pode ser vários: o uso de outro encoding (possivelmente CP850) em vez do seu nativo (provavelmente Cp1252 ou UTF-8), a falta de suporte da fonte do depurador aos caracteres impressos, etc.

Answer (score 3):

## Resposta curta

Porque o Windows foi feito na base da gambiarra e por isso o console usa uma codificação diferente da interface do Visual Studio. Se tu fizer um programa usando GUI tu não vais ter esse problema. Também resolve se tu codificar usando um editor em modo DOS.

## Resposta completa

Porque nos tempos do DOS, não existia unicode ainda. usava-se o padrão ASCII, mas ele define apenas o alfabeto inglês, sem suporte a acentos. Havia entretanto, formas de estender o número de caracteres, mais aí cada sistema definia uma codificação diferente, às vezes mais do que uma, como a versão do DOS em português que definia acentos.

Como era um sistema em modo texto, alguns caracteres eram reservados para linhas, caixas, etc, que podiam ser usados para formar uma interface simplificada. Quando as interfaces gráficas se popularizaram, não tinha mais necessidade de símbolos para linha, caixas e etc, pois a GUI te dá isso. Logo foi feito uma nova codificação, que representa praticamente todas línguas ocidentais. Só que infelizmente, os códigos que representam os acentos mudaram e é impossível escrever um texto em DOS e ler em GUI sem que os acentos se tornem ilegíveis e vice-versa.

A MS poderia ter refeito o console para que usasse a mesma codificação que as janelas, mas não era uma boa opção econômica destacar recursos para isso, pois estava focada em promover aplicações gráficas e era questão complicada que envolvia quebra de retrocompatibilidade, então eles deixaram assim mesmo e DOS nem foi cogitado quando o Window aderiu ao unicode.

### Para resolver você tem quatro opções:

1. Mapear o código de todos os caracteres em modo DOS e trocar os acentos por esses códigos ("Você" se tornaria algo como "Voc\0x79").
2. Usar um editor ou IDE do DOS. Até hoje o dos vem com o comando `edit` e você pode achar versões do Turbo C++ em algum lugar.
3. Usar linux. Pelo menos nas distros que eu usei tanto o console como as janelas usam unicode utf8 e os acentos funcionam corretamente.
4. Executar seu programa numa janela de prompt configurada com o comando `chcp 1252`. Para essa configuração ter efeito, a janela do prompt de comando deve estar usando uma fonte que suporte essa codificação (como "Lucida Console", e não "Raster Font")

Caso decida pela opção 1, você pode saber esse mapeando compilando e rodando um programinha simples como esse abaixo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{     
   for(int i = 0x20; i <= 0xff; ++i){
       cout << "\\x"<< hex << i << "\t=> " << static_cast<char>(i) << endl;
   }  
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Todo letra com acento eu teria que digitar um código no lugar?

Comment: Se eu criar um software no Visual Studio e não fizer alguma gambiarra vai sair sempre desconfigurado quando compilar?

Comment: Sim toda letra com acento teria que digitar um código, mas apenas para programas em modo texto. Quando tu começares a fazer programas em modo janela não vais mais precisar de gambiarra.

Comment: Eu não recomendaria usar os códigos assim. Além de ruim de programar, os códigos da CodePage-850 são obsoletos, e caso você queira rodar seu programa num lugar que suporte Unicode (como Linux) ou pelo menos Windows-1252, aí você vai ter exatamente o mesmo problema só que ao contrário: o código fonte vai ter uma codificação (CP850) e o terminal vai ter outra (windows-1252, unicode, o que for).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#include<tchar.h>
```

Depois use:

```
_tsetlocale(LC_ALL, _T("portuguese"));
```

Daqui pra frente pode mandar `cout << "qq coisa com acentos";` que vai funcionar!