# Problemas com ã e õ em C++

Tags: c++, caracteres

Estou com uma dificuldade com caracteres especiais em C++. Assisti alguns vídeos sobre a impressão de caracteres especiais no console, até aí ok. Consigo imprimir tudo menos ã e õ.

Depois de várias tentativas percebi que os mesmos acentos não aparecem no cmd nem associando eles a valores da tabela ASCI ou até simplesmente digitando no CMD. Uso o windows 8.1, tentei até traduzir para pt-br mas mesmo assim não funcionou.

No código eu já adicionei

`<locale.h>` e chamo a função

`setlocate(LC_ALL, “portuguese”);`

Só que o próprio console não reconhece. No caso só ã e õ não reconhece. Todas as outras acentuações (á, é, í, ó, ú, â, ê, î, ô, û, ç) funcionam normalmente.

O ã no prompt aparece como |=

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Por que no debug do C++ palavras acentuadas e c cedilha aparecendo desconfiguradas?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34758/por-que-no-debug-do-c-palavras-acentuadas-e-c-cedilha-aparecendo-desconfigurad)

Answer (score -1):

Rapaz, eu não sei se vai funcionar para você, mas eu tive problemas parecidos, porém o meu foi fácil de resolver, mesmo usando o `setlocale` não imprimia corretamente. Então depois eu descobri que no sublime, que é o editor de textos que uso para programar, eu tinha que salvar o texto em Western(Windows 1252) em vez de UTF-8, aí quando eu compilava dava tudo certinho.

Só para constar, você ta incluindo os cabeçalhos né?

```
#include <clocale> ou #include <locale.h>
```