# setlocale não funciona no RAD Studio C++ Builder em console apllication

Tags: c++

```
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <tchar.h>
#else
  typedef char _TCHAR;
  #define _tmain main
#endif

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{


    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Por que no debug do C++ palavras acentuadas e c cedilha aparecendo desconfiguradas?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34758/por-que-no-debug-do-c-palavras-acentuadas-e-c-cedilha-aparecendo-desconfigurad)

Comment: Para este caso, não há duplicidade no questionamento. Pois estou utilizando a IDE RAD Studio C++ Builder da Embarcadero.

Comment: O problema é o mesmo, `setlocale` não funcionará em lugar algum pelo mesmos problemas citados na resposta da outra pergunta. A questão não é o RAD a questão é o Windows. A não ser que você esteja falando de um erro bem diferente, mas como não tem detalhes na pergunta então presumo que o erro sejam os caracteres estranhos assim: `Utilizando caracteres e acentuaÃ§Ã£o da lÃ­ngua portuguesa!` se **não for** for problema de caracteres então edite a sua pergunta e **explique**.

Comment: Creio que o problema esta na RAD mesmo, pois na utilizo o CodeBlocks, e nele este comando funciona.

Comment: CodeBlocks não é compilador é IDE, o compilador nele deve ser o Mingw, eu tenho o Mingw aqui e o problema também ocorreu, o teu mingw deve ter parecido funcionar devido a alguma pré-configuração do CodeBlocks

Comment: Sim, no CodeBlocks utilizo o Mingw também, comecei a usar a RAD estes dias, e nela este comando não funciona. Todo material que encontro esta em russo, mandarim ou em algum idioma que desconheço.

Comment: Como eu disse, o teu codeblocks deve ter uma pré-configuração para o terminal exibir a saída com acentos, pois aqui eu compilo as coisas na mão sem IDE e o problema ocorreu também.